# When mutiple MapReduce jobs are chained, is the output of each written to the HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Let us say multiple MapReduce jobs are chained, such as shown below.

```
Map1-Reduce1 -> Map2-Reduce2 -> ... -> MapN-ReduceN
```

Would the output of each MapReduce job be written to the HDFS? For example, would the output of Map1-Reduce1 be written to the HDFS? And In case of failure of tasks in Map2-Reduce2, can Map2-Reduce2 restart by reading the output of Map1-Reduce1, which is already in the HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by extending the `Configured` class and writing multiple job configurations, i.e., one for each `M-R`. The `outputpath` of one `m-r` instances will be served as as input to the second.

Yes you can use `oozie` to serialize your output from one `MapR` to another via `HDFS`. You should checkout `ChainMapper` class in Hadoop.

Comment: I am not trying to achieve anything, but just trying to understand the underlying mechanisms. Do frameworks such as Oozie that allow this kind of chaining force one MapR to write to HDFS when chaining or could it also be saved into disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use oozie or Spring Batch both are suited for your solution. You can write the output of each step to HDFS and read back in next Map Reduce Job.